# Can't see Snowflake tables in Talend

Tags: connection, talend, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to connect to Snowflake via Talend, the connection seems correct, but when i'm trying to add tables i can't see anything.
when i log to Snowflake with my user the tables exists in the database. (same database i'm trying to connect)

I have granted the Role I'm using to the user i'm using and my Role have grants on the Database i'm trying to see the tables from.

[Connection success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORaY8.png)

[Empty tables list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avivN.png)

[Role specification in the connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDDJO.png)

Comment: Are you sure that the Talend user's default role is set to the correct role?  Unless you are specifying a role in your connection information (which you didn't post here), then the user will be logged in as their default role.

Comment: yes I have specified the Role in my connection, and when i check in show grants on Snowflake it says the user is connected to this Role.

Comment: Does the role have usage grants on the database?

Comment: Also, you can try setting the default role "ALTER USER <username> set DEFAULT_ROLE = <rolename>;"

Comment: Looks like you are setting the role correctly in Talend and you've already gotten the advice to check permissions.  Perhaps you could also try another application like DBeaver with our latest JDBC driver just to see if it's specific to Talend?